# On the difference between Malliavin derivative and Gross-Sobolev derivative

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, wiener-measure

Let $W=C_0([0,1],\mathbb R^d)$ be the classical Wiener space equipped with $\mu$ the Wiener measure.
If $F:W\to\mathbb R$ is a cylindrical function of the form

\begin{align*}
F(w)=f(W_{t_1}(w),\cdots,W_{t_n}(w)), f\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)
\end{align*}
where $W_t$ is the $t$-th component projection, we define for $h\in H$ (the Cameron-Martin space),

\begin{align*}
\nabla_h F(w)=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}F(w+\epsilon h)\rvert_{\epsilon=0}
\end{align*}

Notice that $W_t(w+h)=W_t(w)+h(t)$  and then

\begin{align}
\nabla_h F(w)&=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}f(W_{t_1}(w+\epsilon h),\cdots,W_{t_n}(w+\epsilon h))\rvert_{\epsilon=0}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i f(W_{t_1}(w+\epsilon h),\cdots,W_{t_n}(w+\epsilon h))) h(t_i) \rvert_{\epsilon=0}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i f(W_{t_1}(w),\cdots,W_{t_n}(w)) h(t_i).
\end{align}

At this point we can see that the map $h\mapsto \nabla_h F(w)$ defines a random variable taking values in the dual space $H^*$, hence if we identify $H$ with its dual we have that $\nabla F$ is an $H$-valued random variable.
If we extend this operator to all Wiener functionals (using the density of the cylindrical ones) we obtain the so called "Gross-Sobolev" derivative.

This definition looks pretty similar to the definition of the Malliavin derivative, but I don't believe that the Mallivin derivative is a random variable taking values in the Cameron Martin space.

My idea on how things go (I am not completely sure and that's why I am asking you this) is the following:

The last expression above can be written as

\begin{align}
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i f(W_{t_1}(w),\cdots,W_{t_n}(w)) \int_0^1 1_{[0,t_i]}(s)\dot{h}(s)ds\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i f(W_{t_1}(w),\cdots,W_{t_n}(w)) \langle 1_{[0,t_i]},\dot{h}\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\\
&=\langle DF,\dot{h}\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}\\
&=\bigg\langle \int_0^{\cdot}D_rF dr,h\bigg\rangle_{H}=\langle \nabla F,h\rangle_H.
\end{align}

Where $DF$ is the classical Malliavin derivative of $F$. Then if what I've done above is correct the Gross-Sobolev derivative equals the time integral of the Malliavin derivative.
Can we thing of them as being the same since the space $L^2(\mu)$ is isometric and isomorphic to $H$?

Is this correct, or is it just a coincident?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.